# is $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}'$ equal to $\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y' \end{bmatrix}$?

Tags: vectors

where $'$ is the derivative WRT some independent variable that x and y (which are dependent variables) are a function of.

is $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}'$ = $\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y' \end{bmatrix}$ true?

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I do wonder if vectors have this property.

Comment: Write out the limit definition of the derivative and see.

Comment: I see thank you.